# Detect when the Foreground windows changes

Tags: winapi

I know which using the [`GetForegroundWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function i can get the current active window handle, but now `i want to detect when the active window (of any application) changes (become active)`. the first solution which come to my mind  is

1. store the current value (handle) returned by the GetForegroundWindow function.
2. using a timer component check again the value returned by GetForegroundWindow and compare with the old value.

I'm wondering if exist a better way to do this maybe using a windows message or something else.

Comment: I remember there was a trick to listen in on the message queue for a window in Windows 3.x, not sure if that trick still works on Win32

Comment: I hope you're not trying to make sure that your window is always on top of every other window. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx

Comment: @Jim don't worry, I'm not doing that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990.aspx) to install a CBT hook. MSDN describes the [callback function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644977.aspx) you'll provide:

> The system calls this function before activating, creating, destroying, minimizing, maximizing, moving, or sizing a window; before completing a system command; before removing a mouse or keyboard event from the system message queue; before setting the keyboard focus; or before synchronizing with the system message queue. A computer-based training (CBT) application uses this hook procedure to receive useful notifications from the system.

The calls you'll be interested in are the ones where the first parameter is `HCBT_Activate`. The `wParam` parameter will tell you the window handle.

Answer (score 1):

SetWindowsHookEx can be difficult to use since the hook must be placed in a separate dll. An alternative would be [SetWinEventHook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook) with EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, which only requires a running message loop.

Comment: This is rather more than an *"alternative"* to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5876275). It is the go-to solution, both less intrusive and more robust: It doesn't require injecting arbitrary code into processes (potentially destabilizing them) and consequently works with protected processes. [WinEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/what-are-winevents) are for observation, [hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/hooks) are for interception (informing the restrictions in place).